# Any experience with Oz V'Hadar Mishna Berura Hamevuar Set?

Tags: product-recommendation, mishnah-berurah

[This](https://www.greenfieldjudaica.com/mishnah-berurah-hamevoar-peninim---24-vol--set-PMBMSET.html) is the set in question. Does it serve the purpose of being an all in one sefer to see other Poskim other than what's inside a Mishna Berura? How would it compare to the Dirshu? How about when compared to learning Mishna Berura along with Piskei Teshuvos?

Comment: The Dirshu and Piskai are basically additions. The Oz V'hodor are explanations, often brought by later poskim like R Chaim No'eh.